# What are your favorite Eclipse plug-ins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The only plug-ins I use are the ones required to do my job like SoapUI, Maven and SVN.  I'm wondering if maybe there are some plug-ins out there that might make my life easier.  Are there any Eclipse plug-ins that you find invaluable?

Answer (score 13):

[findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) without a doubt!

Answer (score 12):

[Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) for SVN integration

Comment: I think she mentioned Subclipse or an equivalent by mentioning SVN...

Comment: I'm already using this one.  Guess I should have been more specific.

Comment: There's also subversive for SVN, but Subclipse is far superior

Answer (score 8):

Mylyn is pretty cool.

Answer (score 6):

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826/do-you-have-any-recommended-add-onsplugins-for-eclipse).

Comment: I was looking for something like this but it didn't come up in my search....must be because of the slash in the title.  Thanks!

Comment: I remembered coming across it earlier. Everything I would have mentioned had been said over there already.

Answer (score 5):

[EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) for Code Coverage is my favorite (apart from my own plug-ins of course :-) )

Answer (score 5):

[StartExplorer](http://startexplorer.sourceforge.net/) can open files/folders in Explorer *and* cmd.exe, besides copying paths to the clipboard and other things I rarely use -- I use it to make Command windows all the time.

Comment: Cool, always bugged that this feature did not exist, but it does via plug-in.

Answer (score 4):

I'm mainly doing web development so I decided to use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com). It's basically Eclipse pre-packaged with all the web development plug-ins you need. Check it out. It's really good.

Answer (score 4):

[Checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) for code style checking and more.

Answer (score 4):

[Jadclipse](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net) (integration with [Jad](http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html) decompiler)

Comment: JD-Eclipse (Realign edition) is better than Jadclipse.

Comment: I know. Also switched to JD-Eclipse couple years ago

Answer (score 4):

[MouseFeed](http://www.mousefeed.com/)

Whenever you click on a toolbar icon, menu or contextual menu and there is a hot-key which lets you acoomplish the same thing it will display a popup reminding you of it (see the example below).

You'll end up learning the eclipse shortcuts as you use it and become more productive.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) I like better than Subclipse.  It is nice to SVN integrated as a Team provider.  I haven't used Subclipse in a while, but its probably a lot better than it used to be.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [QuantumDB](http://quantum.sourceforge.net), especially on Linux, which has a shortage of decent GUI tools for DB work.

Also [RunJettyRun](http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run) makes running web apps a no-brainer.

Comment: I like DBViewer.  Very leightweight compared to QuantumDB

Answer (score 2):

[QuickREx](http://www.bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/web/QuickREx/toc.html) for all your regular expression needs.

Answer (score 2):

PyDev is pretty awesome. Only works with the new version of Eclipse, though.

Ed

Answer (score 2):

nWire. It's an innovative plugin for exploring Java code. It lets you navigate, search and visualize your code. It is completely addictive. There's a [short demo](http://nwiresoftware.com/introduction/screencast) on the [nWire site](http://nwiresoftware.com/).

Comment: Looks really great, too bad it's not free.

Answer (score 2):

- Subclipse
- Checkstyle
- Findbugs
- Spring IDE
- m2eclipse (Maven plugin)
- PMD
- Jadclipse (decompiler)

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related to programming, but for documentation reasons I like the free version of [XMind](http://www.xmind.net) (Mindmapping tool) and TeXlipse (LaTeX environment, on Sourceforge, sorry, but could not post a second hyperlink) a lot.

I like some of the previously mentioned ones e.g. Findbugs.

And I second Jay R. that I'd rather use Subversive to Subclipse although Subclipse is easier to install (on the Mac at least).

Answer (score 1):

[MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VisualVM for profiling and performance analysis of our java programs.

Comment: Is VisualVM available as Eclipse plugin? I would love to have it inside Eclipse!

Comment: ... integrated with debugger... that would be great!

Comment: Not really integration, but launcher at least: https://visualvm.dev.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html

Answer (score 1):

Working with Visual Dataflex, the [Visual DataFlex Tools for Eclipse](http://resheim.no/vdf) plugin is a must!

Answer (score 1):

Prevously I was using MyEclipse, but now I'm moving to Seam and I'm using [JBoos Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools/)

Answer (score 1):

[ContextMenuPlugin](http://www.geocities.com/richard_hoefter/ContextMenuPlugin/) makes the Windows Explorer context menu available when right-clicking on objects in navigator views, and on editor frames. It passes the clicked file or folder to the selected function.

This is especially valuable if you have useful Explorer extensions. I use this to invoke Tortoise CVS & SVN functions, to open a Command prompt in the corresponding directory, etc.

Comment: The link (GeoCities) doesn't work any more. Any updated URL?

Answer (score 1):

[P4WSAD](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/p4wsad.html). It's great to have Perforce support in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Flex Builder :D

Answer (score 1):

(shameless plug) I like having [FogBugz integrated into Eclipse](http://www.foglyn.com) :-)

Comment: Is there a free or evaluation use of it?

Comment: Sure. You can try it for free in first 45 days. If you don't install a regkey, it will disable itself after this time.

Comment: I read that FogBugz is free for open source development. Does that apply for the Eclipse plugin, too?

Answer (score 1):

[JD-Eclipse Java decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse)

IMO it's much better then [Jadclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/)

Answer (score 1):

- TaskTop is important to keep track of the stuff I have to do
- XText is very impressive technology - what did we do before XText?
- Memory Analyzer is extremely good to find all sorts of memory related issues
- Mint is just.. nice. It colors the outline views with relevant ecore information.
- Atlasian tools...

Answer (score 0):

You might find [fast code](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/) plug-in pretty useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

[JarClassFinder](http://developeriq.in/articles/2007/jun/18/jarclassfinder-and-log-watcher-eclipse-plug-ins/) has been really useful to me.