# What are the best plugins for eclipse available

Tags: eclipse

Can someone provide me a list of the best Eclipse Plugins available?

Comment: Really depends on what specifically you're looking to do.  There are plugins for many different things.  Subversion, Git, XML, HTML/CSS/JS, ColdFusion... the list goes on.

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/369406/796559

Comment: Here is a [list](http://jyops.blogspot.in/2012/01/useful-eclipse-plugins-that-didnt-made.html) of good plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to go is [Eclipse Plugins](http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/index.jsp) where you can find all available plugins. You'll also find a handy search function here.

If you want to know which plugins are most popular, turn your browser to [Top 10 Most Popular Eclipse Plugins](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/top-10-most-popular-eclipse?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+eclipsezone/frontpage+%28Eclipse+Zone%29) or [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/).

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Some of my favorites of all time:

- Mylyn (task-oriented programming)
- TPTP (profiling)
- EclEmma (coverage)
- CodePro Analytix (auditing, test generation, coverage)
- FindBugs (static analysis)
- Jadclipse (decompiler, requires JAD)
- Eclipse Color Theme (text editor highlighting)
- lombok (boilerplate buster, not a real plugin, more of a VM agent)